# Error rendering macro - Could not initialize class org.apache.xmlrpc.util.SAXParsers

Tags: java, maven, xml-rpc, confluence

I'm creating confluence macro which should  execute my Java xml-rpc client.

*I tested my Java xml-rpc client terminating it in eclipse (main function)
-  it works perfectly,*

but when I try to connect it with confluence I get the **error**:

*(macro is successfully installed - error comes as output)*

> **Error rendering macro 'TESTLINK PLUGIN' :
>   Could not initialize class org.apache.xmlrpc.util.SAXParsers**

Can someone help me understanding what's going on here? I read it might be problem with external jar - but given anwesers don't fix my problem.

Also I installed my xmlrpc using *mvn-install* command and adding *dependencies* to my pom.xml, SAXParsers should be included there...

Here is the code I have done so far:

**testlink.java:**

```
package com.project.testlink.api;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;
public class testlink {
    public testlink() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // Substitute your Dev Key Here
    public static final String DEV_KEY =  "zzzzZZz";
    // Substitute your Server URL Here
    public static final String SERVER_URL = "zzzZZZZ/xmlrpc.php";   

       public static String testLinkReport(String link)
       {
        String title="Error Ocurred";
        String tcid = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf("=")+1);
           try
           {
               XmlRpcClient rpcClient;
               XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config;

               config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
               config.setServerURL(new URL(SERVER_URL));
               rpcClient = new XmlRpcClient();
               rpcClient.setConfig(config);       

               ArrayList<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
               Hashtable<String, Object> executionData = new Hashtable<String, Object>();   

               executionData.put("devKey", DEV_KEY);
               executionData.put("testcaseexternalid", tcid);
               params.add(executionData);
               Object[] result = (Object[]) rpcClient.execute("tl.getTestCase", params);

                   Map item = (Map)result[0];
                   title = tcid+":"+ item.get("name").toString();


           }
           catch (MalformedURLException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           catch (XmlRpcException e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return title;
       }

}
```

**mymacro.java:**

```
package com.project.testlink.api;
import java.util.Map;
import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.ConversionContext;
import com.atlassian.confluence.macro.Macro;
import com.atlassian.confluence.macro.MacroExecutionException;

public class mymacro implements Macro {
    public mymacro() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public String execute(Map<String, String> arg0, String arg1, ConversionContext arg2)
            throws MacroExecutionException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return testlink.testLinkReport("HL&item=testcase&id=7780");
    }
    @Override
    public BodyType getBodyType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return BodyType.NONE;
    }
    @Override
    public OutputType getOutputType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return OutputType.BLOCK;
    }
    /*
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println(testlink.testLinkReport("HL&item=testcase&id=7780"));
        }
    */

}
```

**atlassian-plugin.xml:**

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${atlassian.plugin.key}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
    <plugin-info>
        <description>${project.description}</description>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}" />
        <param name="plugin-icon">images/pluginIcon.png</param>
        <param name="plugin-logo">images/pluginLogo.png</param>
    </plugin-info>
    <!-- add our i18n resource -->
    <resource type="i18n" name="i18n" location="testlink"/>

    <xhtml-macro name="TESTLINK PLUGIN" class="com.project.testlink.api.mymacro" key="mymacro" icon="/download/resources/${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}/images/pluginIcon.png">
    <category name="external-content"/> 
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="Testlink" type="string" required="true"/>
    </parameters>
    <description>Inserts a calendar for the week into the current page</description>
    </xhtml-macro>


    <!-- add our web resources -->
    <web-resource key="testlink-resources" name="testlink Web Resources">
        <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>

        <resource type="download" name="testlink.css" location="/css/testlink.css"/>
        <resource type="download" name="testlink.js" location="/js/testlink.js"/>
        <resource type="download" name="images/" location="/images"/>
        <context>testlink</context>
    </web-resource>

</atlassian-plugin>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project.testlink</groupId>
    <artifactId>testlink</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <organization>
        <name>Example Company</name>
        <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
    </organization>
    <name>testlink</name>
    <description>This is the com.project.testlink:testlink plugin for Atlassian Confluence.</description>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
            <artifactId>confluence</artifactId>
            <version>${confluence.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-confluence-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <productVersion>${confluence.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${confluence.data.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                    <enableFastdev>false</enableFastdev>
                    <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                    <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>
                        <!-- Add package to export here -->
                        <Export-Package>
                            com.project.testlink.api,
                        </Export-Package>
                        <!-- Add package import here -->
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional",
                            org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional",
                            *
                        </Import-Package>
                        <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannedDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </scannedDependencies>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <confluence.version>5.10.2</confluence.version>
        <confluence.data.version>5.10.1</confluence.data.version>
        <amps.version>6.2.4</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>1.2.3</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.6</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
        <!-- This key is used to keep the consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the key to generate bundle. -->
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

Added 'exclude' to dependencies like [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/104121/im-blocked-help-cannot-be-cast-to-javax.xml.parsers.saxparserfactory)

And after that i had to delete *SAXParsers* class from *.jar* file, now it works :)

> The problem is that the Apache XML-RPC client library you are using has a multitude of other dependencies that it will bundle into your plugin when you compile, and they clash with libraries already shipped in JIRA.